# Get a single row from a SQLite DB without using an ID

Tags: android, sqlite

The below code gives me single row using id:

```
public DataObject getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_PHN, KEY_PTYPE, KEY_PDATE ,KEY_PNAME, KEY_PNOTE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) cursor.moveToFirst();

        DataObject contact = new DataObject(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5));

        cursor.close();

        return contact;
}
```

but I want is using a string,for eg: if my database is as below, then I want get the whole row, when I say name2 (that means it should return address2 and phno2)

1. name1 address1 phnno1
2. name2 address2 phnno2
3. name3 address3 phnno3
4. name4 address4 phnno4

Comment: You can change your where clause accordingly!

Comment: A query will return every row that match the condition. An PK is not the only way to get one row, if you have a unique constraint somewhere, this is still possible. If not, then you will simply take the first one ... not necessarily the one you want

Comment: What about `KEY_PNAME  + "=?"` instead of `KEY_ID + "=?"` and change the parameter type to a String?

Comment: will try and revert

Comment: Pass the LIMIT, if you have multiple user with same name.

Answer (score 0):

I use your example to build my answer.
You can do :

```
Cursor cursorTable = db.query(CONTACTS,
            new String[]{NAME, ADDRESS, PHNNO},
            NAME + "= ?",
            new String[]{"name2"},
            null,
            null,
            null);
```

But if you want this to return only information for name2 you have to be sure there is only one row with "name2" as NAME